# Nvidia Settings best to reduce tearing

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, graphics, nvidia-settings, screen-tearing

I'm trying to reduce video tearing. (Noticeable in games and youtube videos when full screen. On a 16:9 1080p monitor.)

I have read several forums and tried changing refresh rate using compizmanager. I have a second monitor which support maximum of 4:3 1024x768. I have switched this off in settings.

I'm running a basic 3D racing game called little street racers on Ubuntu 14.04. I am seeing a small amount of tearing and am wondering what the best configuration is to reduce it.

There are settings in the nvidia-settings panel for High Quality Image or Performance. Would high quality be best?

There is a vsync option in this game should I select it?

I'm running medium detail at 1080p on a 17" Samsung Monitor with refresh rate set to auto. I'm unsure what he maximum refresh rate of the monitor is - again how should I best configure?

Intel® Core™ i5-4460 (3.2 GHz, 4-core)
NVIDIA® GT 705 2GB / 1GB

Hope someone can offer some tips.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Vsync tends to solve this problem at expense of additional processing. As with many video settings/troubleshooting, just try it and see how it works. Vsync is not like other finicky hardware settings that will cause your nouveau/nvidia driver to crash until backed out.

I'm assuming the max refresh rate on your monitor is around 60hz. You'd probably know if you had purchased a 120hz monitor.

Comment: yes it is a max of 60Hz I believe. cvt shows 60.0+ (unsure what the plus sign means!) I've switched detail to low and switched both monitors on to maximum resolutions of 1080p and 1024x768 refresh rate of 60Hz. Vsync turned on in game. Not noticing tearing. Think the low detail and turning back on the vsync may have improved it - although I don't want to speak too soon.

Comment: Vsync will have fixed it. Vsync specifically fixes/stops tearing by syncing the frames with the monitor's vertical refresh rate. Detail quality will only affect your performance (FPS), not the tearing.